# How to get the source model of a QSortFilterProxyModel in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, model, qstandarditemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a QStandardItemModel that is set as source of QSortFilterProxyModel using setSourceModel().

How can I access the QStandardItemModel? I need to know this in order to iterate over the unmodified data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yourQSortFilterProxyModelinstance->sourceModel() and cast it to QStandardItemModel*